# Searching via attributes in Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With Ember-Data, it's possible to find a model instance by its id:

```
App.Person.find(1)
```

What if you want to find a model instance by another attribute, such as `token`. Is it possible to do something like:

```
App.Person.find_by(token: "ASDFGASDFASDF")
```

If so, should we be concerned about indexing searchable columns. How would that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ArrayController should have a [`findBy`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_findBy) method, which will return the first child element that matches your query. Alternatively you could use [`filterBy`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_filterBy), which returns all elements that match.

As for indexing, that's something you might want to look at to increase performance, but that would be done on your server and depends on your setup.

Comment: Thanks again, Chopper. You've helped me out a lot.